# javascript: выделение подстроки, используя регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки, подстрока

Приветствую

Подскажите как с помощью регулярных выражений можно выполнить следующую операцию:

есть строки вида

1) "xxxxx"

2) 'yyyyy'

3) zzzzz

как из таких строк выделить xxxxx, yyyyy, zzzzz соответственно?

Т.е. нужно выделить строку, расположенную внутри кавычек (" или ') в начале и конце строки или если таких кавычек нет взять строку без изменения.

Comment: А какие тут требования? `.replace(/^['"]+|["']+$/g, '')`  подойдет, если надо удалить все кавычки в начале и конце строки, без проверки на наличие парности и т.д. Что если строка только начинается с кавычек? Начинается с одной, заканчивается другой? Приведите пример своего неработающего кода, так будет понятнее, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const strings = [
`"xxxxx"`,
`'yyyyy'`,
`zzzzz`
];

console.log(strings.map(string => string.replace(/['"]?([^'^"]*)['"]?/, '$1')));
```

---

Вторая попытка:

```js
const strings = [
`"xxxxx"`,
`'yyyyy'`,
`"тут находится строка и 'маленькая подстрока' и строка закрыта кавычами, которые и требуется убрать, не трогая внутренние"`,
`zzzzz`
];

console.log(strings.map(string => string.replace(/(^['"]|['"]$)/g, '')));
```

Comment: тут есть пара моментов - 1) в твоем коде ``xxx'` - это корректный формат, а это не так 2) в середине строки `'"` также пропадут (хотя тут могу ошибаться)

Comment: Строка, расположенная между кавычек, подразумевает что внутри неё кавычек нет. Кавычка закрылась - строка кончилась. Про формат вообще не понял. Уточните вопрос

Comment: Darth, простой пример: `"тут находится строка и 'маленькая подстрока' и строка закрыта кавычами, которые и требуется убрать, не трогая внутренние"`

Comment: @Zhihar обновил ответ

Comment: проблема с кавычками в середине исправлено, все супер, буду использовать этот код. Но чисто для чистоты эксперимента: 1)  хотелось бы, чтобы строка вида `"разные кавычки в начале и в конце'` считалась ошибочной 2) из строки вида `"часть строки" и 'часть строки'` или `"часть строки" и "часть строки"` никакие кавычки не вырезались, но это уже избыточно, просто интересно, есть ли универсальный способ таких преобразований

Comment: @Zhihar Все требвания к заданию должны быть в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях.